# JButtons MouseEvents

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I want my buttons to change color when mouse is on them (hover), when they are pressed (active) and stay this way until user will choose other options. So one of them will be always choosen.

I have three buttons - with cricle, square and traingle. My code:

```java
private static MouseListener ButtonMouseListener = new MouseAdapter () {

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
            Component source = evt.getComponent(); 
            source.setBackground(new Color(91, 90, 90));
        }    

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
            Component source = evt.getComponent();
            source.setBackground(new Color(64, 64, 64));
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
            Component source = evt.getComponent();
            source.setBackground(new Color(46, 46, 46));
        }
    };
```

So I want buttons to change color when hovering over them `(mouseEntered)`, and again change color to default when someone stops hovering (that's why I have `mouseExited`). The next thing is that I want them to change color when they are choosen, so `mousePressed` . The problem is that when I move the cursor outside the button it changes to another color because of `mouseExited` and I don't want that. It has to stay the 'pressed color' until user chooses another of three buttons. I have no idea how to achieve that, I tried different options but nothing works the way I want.

Comment: Try adding a Component field to the class, then in onPressed check if the field is equal to source and if not, change the field's color to the default (if it's not null of course). Then change the field to source. Then in mouseExited check if the field is equal to source and if so, don't change the background

Comment: I understand everything but the first part - I declared ```Component b1``` in this class but how should I initialize it? It needs to be the one button which is pressed but how do I know which one is it? Sorry, this is my first encounter with GUI.

Comment: reading from your code, expecting everything works as you described, the `source` in each method should be the the `Component` you clicked / made an action with right? So just set the `Component b1` to the source, in the beginning it could be set to null for example

Comment: Okay so after a long time fiddling with the code, understanding what's going on I did it! Thank you so much, your idea is very smart and simple!

Answer (score 1):

1. For entry color change you need to implement the Event->Mouse->`mouseEntered`. Make sure you are implementing it on `mouseExited`
2. On mouse pressed color change you need to implement Event->Action. Inside `actionPerformed`, you can set the button color. For example :

   ```
   jButton7.setBackground(new Color(11, 118, 219));
   jButton1.setBackground(new Color(15,44,123));
   jButton8.setBackground(new Color(15,44,123));
   jButton9.setBackground(new Color(15,44,123));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JToggleButton` instead of `JButton` since they have their own UI property for selection (pressed) background. You can override it like this:

`UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.GREEN);`

An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of what I would do:

```
public class ToggleButtonsExample extends JFrame {
    private static final Color PRESSED_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
    private static final Color HOVER_COLOR = Color.RED;

    public ToggleButtonsExample() {
        super("Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JToggleButton button1 = new JToggleButton("button1");
        JToggleButton button2 = new JToggleButton("button2");
        JToggleButton button3 = new JToggleButton("button3");
        final Color defaultBackgroundColor = button1.getBackground();

        MouseListener hoverColorMouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                Component component = e.getComponent();
                component.setBackground(HOVER_COLOR);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                Component component = e.getComponent();
                component.setBackground(defaultBackgroundColor);
            }
        };

        List<AbstractButton> buttons = Arrays.asList(button1, button2, button3);
        buttons.forEach(this::add);
        buttons.forEach(b -> b.addMouseListener(hoverColorMouseListener));

        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", PRESSED_COLOR);
            new ToggleButtonsExample().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

And a preview image:

[image: preview]